# Remove all aria data when cloning

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, validation

I am using jquery validate for my form validation, but when i am cloning a form that already had been checked its cloning

```
aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true"
```

Any lead on reseting the aria without using removeAttr ?

Thanks for your helps !
Jonathan.

Comment: Please show your code that clones the form element; and why is it required that we don't use `removeAttr()`? And do you need to remove the attribute, or the attribute-value?

Comment: I finally decided to create a variable with my html form. Thanks for your help.